# How do I debug my vimrc file?

Tags: vimrc

I have a problem in Vim, and I think it may be in my `vimrc` file (or have been *told* it could be my `vimrc` file).

How do I verify this? If it *is* my `vimrc` file, how do I know where *exactly* the problem lies?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is to start Vim with the default settings:

```
vim -u NONE -U NONE -N
```

The `-u NONE` prevents Vim from loading your vimrc, `-U NONE` prevents Vim from
loading your gvimrc, and `-N` tells Vim to use no-compatible mode (this isn't
required, but most Vim users are not used to "compatible" mode).
Note that the `NONE` is *required* to be in all-caps.

In Windows you can [add these flags by creating a new shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/29569/how-to-add-command-line-options-to-shortcut)<sup>1</sup>.

- If the problem stays, then you know it's *not* something in your vimrc.
- If the problem disappears, you now it's caused by *something* in your vimrc
  file.

## It's not my vimrc!

Hurray! Go and ask your question. Be sure to mention that you tried starting Vim
without a vimrc file!

## So it's my vimrc, now what?

If you haven't already, you probably want to save a backup copy of your vimrc
file first.

### Check the plugins

The next thing you probably want to do is disable all plugins first; plugins can
alter quite a bit in Vim. If this fixes the problem, then try to find out
*which* plugin by re-enabling them one-by-one. After you've found out which
plugin exactly causes the problem, you can try & fix it by reading this plugin's
documentation, and/or by asking a question tagged with `plugin-<name>`.

If it's *not* a plugin, and you don't have *any* idea what's causing your
problem, then it's a trial-and-error procedure. Comment out one or more lines in
your vimrc, start Vim, check if the problem occurs, and repeat this procedure
until the problem stops occurring. The fastest way of doing this is:

1. Comment out (or remove) about half your vimrc file.
2. Restart Vim, or open a new Vim (reloading the vimrc is *not* good enough, as
   settings aren't unset).
3. Is the problem now gone? Put back the part you removed out (keeping Vim
   open and using undo is useful here) and repeat step 1 on the part you added
   back.
4. Does the problem still occur? Go to step 1.

In the end you should have a single option or a combination of a few options
that causes your problem. You can find out more about any option in Vim by
using:

```
:help 'option_name'
```

The quotes are important here, it *usually* works without them, but sometimes
you end up on the wrong page if you omit them.

If you're still confused after reading the help page, you know where to ask a
question ;-)

## Debugging a single plugin

If you want to isolate a single plugin, perhaps to ask a question about it, you want to load as little as
possible but *still* load the plugin; you can easily do this with Vim's packages
feature. This requires Vim 8 or a reasonably recent version of Neovim.

1. Create a new empty directory; we'll use the `~/plugin` path in this example.
   Now put the plugin in the regular `pack/plugins/start/$name` directory. For
   example:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/fatih/vim-go.git ~/plugin/pack/plugins/start/vim-go
   ```
2. Create a `test-vimrc` file with the following contents; this will ensure that
   Vim will load plugins from the `~/plugin` directory and *not* the `~/.vim`
   directory:

   ```
   set nocompatible
   set packpath=~/plugin,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/plugin/after
   packloadall!

   syntax on
   filetype plugin indent on
   ```
3. Start Vim with:

   ```
   vim -U NONE -u ~/test-vimrc
   ```

   You now have a minimal vimrc with just this single plugin.

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup> For example: on 64 bit Windows, the shortcut would look something like this: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\vim.exe" -u NONE -U NONE -N`. To create it, right click in File Explorer where you want the shortcut, then select New -> Shortcut and paste the shortcut text. You may need to change the Vim path if your Vim is installed in another location.

Comment: This technique is called [Binary Search Fault Localization](http://of-vim-and-vigor.blogspot.ca/2013/04/bisectly.html).

Comment: After you figure out your bug, this would be a great time to start keeping your .vimrc under version control :) It's almost always going to be one of the last changes you made to it that made stuff behave strangely.

Comment: You don't need `-U NONE` if you have `-u NONE`.

Comment: @MartinTournoij I [suggested an edit](https://vi.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2211) to make it easier for a first-time reader to understand. I hope you like it. Thanks!

Comment: I've come to prefer `vim --clean` for many situtations. Besides being easier to type, it's equivalent to `-u DEFAULTS -U NONE -i NONE` plus a few more bits like excluding $HOME from $RUNTIMEPATH. `-u DEFAULTS` uses `defaults.vim` as vimrc...which means Vim is actually usable while you debug.

Comment: Yeah, `vim --clean` is clearly the easiest way now @BLayer; but that didn't exist yet when I wrote this.  I'm surprised no one provided an answer with that yet. I'll update this one.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I know you didn't forget about it or anything. I, though, had been using the long form even while `--clean` existed...until I eventually wised up. ;)

Comment: Yeah sure @BLayer; I won't have time in the coming days to do a proper write-up anyway (not that it's *that* much work, but I like to test out these sort of things to make sure I get all details correct, and also need to look at the details for neovim). I'll accept it and it'll be on top, and this answer is still useful for people with older Vims.

Comment: Oh, wow, I wasn't expecting anything like that. That's a magnanimous (regardless of how much rep you have) and selfless offer. Thanks very much! I'll post it tomorrow some time and I'll take a look at the neovim side to check for any differences. Cheers.

Comment: @MartinTournoij after I first posted it I wondered if making it the accepted answer was ideal. I've since edited it so it stands alone better or at least stands as an equal-footing companion to this one...the legacy and the updated follow-up. Regardless, I'm good with whatever way you want to go.

Comment: Coolio @BLayer; I'll have a look in a few days

Comment: Hi @MartinTournoij ... I had forgotten about what we discussed above until just now. Did you ever have a chance to look at my answer? Cheers.

Answer (score 41):

There is `-D` Vim parameter specially for debugging which will go to debugging mode after executing the first command from a script.

E.g. to run Vim in debug mode without any plugins, run as:

```
vim --noplugin -D
```

Type `n`/`next` to parse the next line and keep pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

And `cont` or `q` to go back to `vim` interface.

If you're using a GUI version, put a `gui` command in your vimrc to start the debugging right after that command.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> for list of available commands

Read more:

- [Debug unexpected option settings](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Debug_unexpected_option_settings) at Vim tips wiki
- [`:help debug-scripts`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#debug-scripts)

Comment: This was most helpful in finding a simple mistake in .vimrc file that was causing an error message.  Worth trying this first as it's quick to do.

Comment: @kenorb this command is freaking awesome, save me from going to another editor.

Answer (score 22):

As already mentioned, first try `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N` to make sure your vanilla vim is working fine.

Then start vim normally and check

```
:messages
```

from inside vim after the problem, which will show all warnings and errors.

Finally start vim with the following command

```
vim -V9logfile.log
```

which will create a logfile called `logfile.log`, `-V9` is the logging level and try to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 14):

One more tip: as caveman as it may seem, I do like adding :echom "message" to my .vimrc to see whats being executed and what is not.

For example

```
if executable('ag')
  :echom "AG FOUND"

  ...
endif
```

This helps me quickly see if the if block is being executed, etc. The message will be printed on the console next time you start vim.

Comment: And if you use `echom` another interesting command is `:messages` to get the full log of the messages echoed. It can sometimes be useful to look at them after the startup.

Comment: This is almost what I needed, I want to see what the value of cpoptions is at a point in my vimrc, how do I echo the output of ":set cpoptions?" ?

Comment: @MikeLippert you can use `echom &cpoptions`. Interactively, `:verbose set cpoptions?` is a bit nicer

Answer (score 12):

One thing that I've found helps is keeping a collection of variables that toggle parts of your `.vimrc` so you can disable or enable portions of it without having to comment stuff out. It also has the pleasant side effect of forcing you to think about the organization of your `.vimrc`.

```
" feature toggles in vimrc
let g:vimrc_feat_pathogen               = 1
let g:vimrc_feat_core_minimal           = 1
let g:vimrc_feat_matchit                = 1
let g:vimrc_feat_options                = 1
let g:vimrc_feat_colors_and_highlight   = 1
let g:vimrc_feat_key_rebinding_arpeggio = 1
let g:vimrc_feat_key_rebinding          = 1
let g:vimrc_feat_autocommand_group      = 1
let g:vimrc_feat_custom_definitions     = 1
let g:vimrc_feat_load_opam              = 1
```

Here's an example of a section guarded by an `if`:

```
if g:vimrc_feat_core_minimal
    set nocompatible
    filetype plugin indent on
    syntax on
endif
```

Answer (score 6):

*If you are using a version of Vim prior to 8.0.0716 or Neovim build #9907 skip this and jump to [the answer posted by @MartinTournoij](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/11054) which describes the Vim flags available to you for setting up clean configurations.*

### Overview

This answer describes the command-line flag `--clean`, introduced in Vim 8, as a recommended alternative to [`-u NONE`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-u) and related flags.

If you're not familiar with said flags or vimrc debugging in general you may want to start with a read of the answer linked above then return here to get up to speed on more recent developments.

Either way, here is a summary of the flags in question:

- [`-u NONE`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-u) : Skip all initializations from files and environment variables.
- [`-U NONE`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-U) : Don't load any "gvimrc" (GUI initialization) files. Redundant when `-u NONE` is present.
- [`-i NONE`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-i) : Don't read/write the "viminfo" file.
- [`-N`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-N) : Equivalent to `:set nocompatible`. In other words, *don't enable emulation of legacy editor 'vi'*. Usually used with `-u NONE`.

### Issues with '-u NONE'

`-u NONE` is fairly well known and widely used to help debug issues with Vim that are thought to be caused by user/local configuration. It has some pitfalls, though.

#### "I feel like a Vim noob!"

With `-u NONE` enabled you may find Vim annoying if not difficult to use. For example, command-line history and command and filename completion are gone which means having to type everything manually. File type detection is disabled so you won't have syntax highlighting to make things more legible. And surely worst of all, `'compatible'` will be enabled which makes Vim behave in ways alien to many modern Vimmers.

The `'compatible'` part can be solved by using `-N` with `-u NONE` but everything else is off/default and you still have the potential issue described in the next section.

#### "When you say 'NONE' don't you really mean 'SOME'?"

There are additional local customizations one can apply besides those found in your personal vimrc file. For an example here's an excerpt from a question @Rick pointed out to me where he asked about disabling such settings:

> the runtimepath option still contains ~/.vim and, notably, ~/.vim/after, (so e.g. if I subsequently turn on file type detection and change filetype, code in ~/.vim/after/syntax/the_relevant_filetype.vim will be executed).

Source: [How can I get Vim to ignore all user configuration, as if it were freshly installed?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6112)

`-u NONE` is of no help here. (The top answer there is, spoiler alert, `--clean`. ;)

### Enter 8.0.0716 and 8.0.1554

Vim patch 8.0.0716 gives us solutions to the issues detailed in the "noob" section, above, and patch 8.0.1554 covers the issue described in the section following it. (These patches were merged into Neovim but they are necessarily scaled down quite a bit. See below.)

#### defaults.vim and 'DEFAULTS'

First up is the introduction of `DEFAULTS` as an argument to [`-u`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-u), e.g. `vim -u DEFAULTS myfile`.  Instead of loading no vimrc file like `-u NONE` this will load [`$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim). This file contains a sane, stable configuration that makes Vim far more usable while being unlikely to impede your debugging efforts. That configuration includes all of those things I mentioned as missing in the "noob" section above. (If some included configuration *does* impact your debugging take a look in the file because it contains instructions on how to reset individual settings as well how to revert a number of the commands it runs.)

Side note: I actually load defaults.vim as one of the first steps in all of my vimrc files. Even if you override/revert a setting or two it'll likely reduce the size of your vimrc.

#### The '--clean' Flag

The next thing we get from the patch, and the reason we're all here, is the flag `--clean`. It has an effect *similar* to using these flags: `-u DEFAULTS`, `-U NONE` and `-i NONE` but with an added punch. I'll turn to [`:h --clean`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#--clean) for the details:

- initializations from files and environment variables is skipped
- `'runtimepath'` and `'packpath'` are set to exclude home directory entries (does not happen with `-u DEFAULTS`).
- the `defaults.vim` script is loaded, which implies `'nocompatible'`: use Vim defaults
- no `gvimrc` script is loaded
- no viminfo file is read or written

Note the second item which solves the problem of loading "after" files and the like.

### Neovim

There is no defaults.vim file included with Neovim because it's default settings are considered sane and are familiar to modern users. Most signficantly there's no `'compatible'` setting; no vi compatibility, period, in Neovim. So `--clean` is more limited though still may be useful. It is equivalent to `-u NONE` and `-i NONE` and, again, quoting the [the documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#--clean):

- Skips initializations from files and environment variables.
- No `'shada'` file is read or written.
- Excludes user directories from `'runtimepath'`

And as with Vim, when you use `--clean` you won't have to worry about "after" files (third bullet).

Comment: Is -Nu NONE any better? I use that more often than -u NONE, though I do really like clean.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ah, he does mention `-N` already. Perfect. But my next edit I'll do so, too, because I noticed a good place to note it.

Comment: The other downside to -u NONE is that while it ignores _almost_ all configuration [it doesn’t ignore _everything_](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6112/). This isn’t just academic! I originally wrote that question after a testing mishap when a plug-in got picked up that I was specifically trying to ignore.

Comment: @Rich Great info which I'll link/integrate soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vey simple procedure to get you started.

1. comment out contents of your entire .vimrc file
2. reload your .vimrc by running `:source %` or `:so $MYVIMRC`
3. uncomment a discreet part of the file (generally starting from the top)
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until you find the error.
5. fix the error.

Comment: This answer could be a lot better if you properly capitalised and punctuated it.

Comment: Highly recommend doing this with a binary search.

Answer (score 1):

My vimrc loading time was very slow, around 400ms, and i reduced it to 20ms only by removing this line:

```
silent !mkdir ~/.config/nvim/backups > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Make sure you don't have calls to external commands like that.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a useful tidbit, but it's quite a bit more specific than the very general question asked. It might be better added as an answer to e.g. [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6298/slow-startup-time-unrelated-to-plugins), or, if you're just looking to share knowledge, you could perhaps ask-and-answer your own question?